# RevisionRepository return entity with different List implementation (PersistanceBag ->ListProxy)

Tags: java, jpa, testing, hibernate-envers, spring-data-envers

```
org.springframework.data.repository.history.RevisionRepository
Entity entity = repository.findLastChangeRevision(entity.getId()).get().getEntity();
```

return entity with list as ListProxy.

Normal CrudRepository

```
repository.findById(id)
```

return the same entity with identical content, but list with type PersistentBag.

This difference case problem with asserting this two object in integration tests.

Any solutions?

Comment: How are you asserting on the result? Lists are usually equal as long as they contain the same elements, regardless of specific implementation

Comment: I assert by assertEquals 2 entities which contain these lists. Temporaty i made my method which makes comparison field by field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't test for equality but for equality of content. How to do that depends on your testing and assertion library you use.

AssertJ for example has [`containsExactlyInAnyOrder`](https://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/core/api/org/assertj/core/api/ListAssert.html#containsExactlyInAnyOrder(ELEMENT...)) and [`containsExactly`](https://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/core/api/org/assertj/core/api/ListAssert.html#containsExactly(ELEMENT...)) for this.

**Some vague background**

Hibernate and in general all JPA implementations and most ORMs either replace/manipulate the byte code of your classes or use proxies or special implementations in order to do their job. One important part is dirty-tracking, i.e. JPA will notice when you change an entity, e.g. by adding an element into a collection. In order to do that they'll have to do some magic like replacing your list by some other class that notifies the JPA implementation of such actions.

For that reason you might find implementations from your JPA implementation in your entity instances.

Comment: I did as you said, but I'm curious why it works that way

Comment: I added a section to the answer.